# How long to keep neutered dog from jumping?

Tags: dogs, health, neutering

I have a small toy poodle that just got neutered yesterday. She's already fully awake and acting mostly normal, just a bit slower. At first she wasn't moving much so I took the cone off, and she immediately sat and walked around a bit. So I am keeping it off and keeping an eye on her to make sure she wont lick the incision.

Yesterday, in the 30 seconds that took me to go get some water, she had jumped in my bed (she always sleep there). I let her rest there and took her down when it looked like she wanted to get down.

My question is, how long I can let her jump up and down by herself until the risk of tearing her stitches ends? Right now I just keep a close eye on her 24/7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopping a dog from jumping and running is always going to be hard to do. So just stop her as much as you can.

Ive seen people say 1-2 weels but to be safe I would recommend not until the stitches are removed only then can you 100% guarantee the incision has healed. This will make sure nothing serious can happen.

Answer (score 3):

You can lower the chances of a dog jumping by providing any kind of step or ramp. Use sturdy cardboard boxes, foot rests, bottle crates  or whatever you can find that

- won't slip over the floor
- has a non-slip surface and
- won't give under the dog's wheight.